# Prevent double spacing between childs inside RecyclerView GridLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have the following ImageView for single image in GridLayout with 2 columns. But it adds double margins at the middle (because both has marginLeft and marginRight). How can I prevent this?

This is the xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/default_image" />
```

Comment: Have you got the solution from below answers, you didn't communicate further which is mandatory for keeping the community helpful. Please mark the answer accepted which one is useful to you or make comments with further questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split the left & right margin values between the childs and the RecyclerView itself.

Like, if you intend to have 8dp margin on left & right and 8dp in middle, set 4dp left & right margin into childs layout and 4dp to RecyclerView layout.

If you have multiple rows, similar technique can be applied for top & bottom margins too.

Your child ImageView layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/default_image" />
```

Your RecylerView gridlayout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace the code with below one:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/default_image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

it's convenient to use the RecyclerView‘s addItemDecoration(ItemDecoration decor).it would be better than in xml.